# How to add JTextField whenever the button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I am practising Java Swing and I am trying to create a GPA calculator. I am having a hard time with my code, how can I add text fields whenever the `JButton` "add" is clicked? I also want the text fields to align vertically when the button is clicked. Should I use a layout or something?

You can check my screenshot as well.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
public class gwa implements ActionListener, java.awt.event.ActionListener{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
    //button
    JButton buttonAdd = new JButton("Add");
    buttonAdd.setBounds(30, 30, 80, 34);
    buttonAdd.addActionListener(new gwa());
    
    //textfield
    JTextField gradeField = new JTextField();
    gradeField.setBounds(150, 30, 100, 35);
    JTextField unitsField = new JTextField();
    unitsField.setBounds(300, 30, 100, 35);
    
    //panel
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(buttonAdd);
    panel.add(gradeField);
    panel.add(unitsField);

    //frame
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

Comment: *"Should I use a layout or something?"* Yes. Unless you know the logic well enough to *write* a layout manager, you should use existing ones. Note the a `JTextField` with a number of columns set (either in the constructor or via the relevant method) has a natural size appropriate for the content and font size. It's way more accurate than you (or I) could guess.  *"How to add JTextfield whenever the button is clicked?"* I suggest using a `JList`. It will stack entries vertically by default, and can have a text field assigned as a cell editor.

Comment: @AndrewThompson did you mean `JTable` instead of `JList`?

Comment: @gthanop The thing that popped into my head was a list, given it is 'more like' a combo box in being well suited to a 'single line of text'. But a `JTable` might also have value here, especially if the app. needs to present several aspects (columns) of information for each item.

Comment: @AndrewThompson but `JList`s do not support cell editors, or am I missing something?

Comment: @gthanop . . . ‍♂️ No. in this case it's me that missed that a cell editor only applies to a `JTable`. Thanks for the corection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way – but not the only way – is to use [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GwaAdder {
    private static final int  COLUMNS = 10;

    private GridBagConstraints  gbc;
    private JPanel  textFieldsPanel;

    private void addTextField(ActionEvent event) {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(COLUMNS);
        gbc.gridy++;
        textFieldsPanel.add(textField, gbc);
        textFieldsPanel.revalidate();
        textFieldsPanel.repaint();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextFieldsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtons(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtons() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(this::addTextField);
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createTextFieldsPanel() {
        textFieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(COLUMNS);
        textFieldsPanel.add(textField, gbc);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textFieldsPanel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140, 200));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new GwaAdder().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

The [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) is implemented using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). When you change the GUI after it is initially displayed (as the above code does in method `addTextField`), you usually need to call method [revalidate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) (in class `javax.swing.JComponent`) followed by method [repaint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) (in class `java.awt.Component`).

How it looks when I run the above code:

[image: animated gif of running app]

Answer (score 1):

You should first give your button's Action event the panel, and then do the Action
My English is not good, so I use translation software to answer, please forgive me